# Camel Java Routebuilder Timeout

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a Camel routebuilder with the following route defined:

```
from(route).routeId("route1")
                .bean(myBean)
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
                .to("log:get-data-request?level=INFO&ShowHeaders=false&ShowBody=true")
                .to(myURI)
                .to("log:get-data-response?level=INFO&ShowHeaders=false&ShowBody=true")
```

Is it possible to add a timeout to this route so that if the reply from myURI takes longer than say 10 seconds it throws an exception of some sort?

At the moment if there is no immediate response my application just appears to hang on the request waiting.

Comment: http://camel.apache.org/graceful-shutdown.html ?

Comment: From the code above I asume that you do a http call with the camel http component. Maybe setting, for example, the soTimeout to 10 seconds is a solution for you?

Comment: @soilworker do you have an example of how I might incorporate the soTimeout into my routebuilder? I have seen this done using pure Java code but not as part of the routebuilder itself

Comment: See http://camel.apache.org/http.html. 
"httpClient.XXX
null
Setting options on the HttpClientParams. For instance httpClient.soTimeout=5000 will set the SO_TIMEOUT to 5 seconds."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this:

1. Already explained by @soilworker - http://localhost:9080/myservice?httpClient.soTimeout=5000. See unit test [here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/camel/trunk/components/camel-jetty/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/jetty/HttpProducerSOTimeoutTest.java?view=markup&pathrev=781775).
2. This is not the right way but will work in a simple scenario.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       JndiContext jndiContext = (new SetJndiContext()).SetJndiContext();
       CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(jndiContext);
       try {
            //camelContext.addRoutes(new MyRouteBuilder());
            camelContext.addRoutes(new FileDownloadRouter());
            camelContext.start();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            camelContext.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
   ```

Basically, when your routes starts running, the context will automatically shutdown in 10s. Again this is not the ideal way to do it. Option 1 is the right way to do it, but this method will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify what kind of endpoint is **toUri**?

- In case it's an HTTP[1] endpoint and you are calling a REST endpoint you can setUp the Apache HTTP Component below the http call with the SocketTimeout that you want.
- If you want to call another Camel endpoint you could use the Async [2] strategy that Camel provides. With a Future Exchange you can set the time that the original endpoint will wait. However the second thread could keep alive and finish the tasks.

[1] http://camel.apache.org/http.html
[2] http://camel.apache.org/async.html